# Packaging .txt files for use in python executable using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, packaging, python-packaging

I've built a hangman game with the use of other .txt files in the same directory containing the word banks for the hangman game, these are opened from within the hangman.py file, when i use pyinstaller to package i use `path\to\pyinstaller.exe hangman.py --onefile` but this doesn't allow the use of the .txt files from within the executable. How do i package the .txt files so the executable can run properly?

Comment: Try `path\to\pyinstaller.exe  --onefile hangman.py`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'path/to/file.txt:path/inside/exe' hangman.py
```

or editing the spec file with a list of files, i.e.

```
added_files = [
     ( 'src/README.txt', '.' )
     ( '/mygame/sfx/*.mp3', 'sfx' ),
     ]
a = Analysis(...
     datas = added_files,
     ...
     )
```

Comment: if there are multiple txt files, the first option wouldnt work, right? and after editing the spec file to i have to rerun the pyinstaller command? or would it work regardless if the executable isnt in the same machine?

Comment: After you edit it, you rerun pyinstaller on the spec file: pyinstaller myscript.spec

Comment: when editing the spec file is it an absolute path? or relative path? i apologize for the trivial questions, im new to the whole packaging files other than .py with pyinstaller

Comment: You can use relative paths, starting from the root directory